# IOS: don't change color UIButton when it's pushed

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

when I push a custom UIButton it change its color and become more dark but I want that its color don't change when I push it, how can I do this?

Comment: By custom UIButton you mean a button with image? You can do it by setting the same image for highlighted state, but that's a bad ux design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the buttons colors for each control state you want to customize

Comment: is there a fast wat to do it?

Comment: yes, set the states in your code when you add the button to the screen or if you are using IB, in your viewDidLoad method